Force reloading of a useQuery (not refetching)
There is an issue I've got into recently.
Let's say, there are a few components [A1, A2, A3] rendered. There is another component [B] rendered. B is not related to A1, A2, A3 in any hierarchical way (the components are peers, no parent-child connection).
A1, A2, and A3 have data from a query called aQuery. aQuery is refetched every minute. The data is stale by default.
There is a button in B component clicking on which makes all instances of aQuery invalid. (Something like Refresh Data).
I have 2 states supported in A:

Loading - I show a message "Loading data..."
Fetching / refetching - I show the previous data until new one is loaded.

And the issue is in a case where I click this button and I have to show "Loading data...". Each click on a button from B makes all aQuery's get refetched. However, I need it to be reloaded (because I need to render over the components inside A).
In a nutshell:
Is there any way in react-query to invalid a query in a way to make it get reloaded not refetched?

Yes, there is a way to do what you intend to do, and it's using the resetQueries method. It works similar to the invalidateQueries which you might be using already with the difference that it restores the query to the initial state meaning that if an initialData existed for the query it would be restore to that, but in your case, it would just empty the cache, and the query instances will be in a status of isPending instead of isRefetching.
So in your case, try:
const ComponentB = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  const handleReset = () => queryClient.resetQueries({queryKey: ['aQuery']});

  return (
    <button onClick={handleReset}>
      Reset
    </button>
  ); 
};


oh yeah, great, thanks!
i've tried it out. it helps. however, there is one more issue. for example, if i update the props of an original query, f. e.

the query has [aQuery, { a: 1, b: 2 }]
then it changes to [aQuery, { a: 2, b: 2}]

then resetQueries doesn't trigger reloading :(

it seems like it changes the initial state in case of having the second version of a query and that's why it doesn't trigger realoding.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/reset-queries-forked-q6g7yj - here is the link, you can check.
After clicking on one of 'Increase A', clicking on Reset stops reloading it.

Apparently "keepPreviousData" is the one to blame here, if you remove it it will work as you expect it to behave, do you need the keepPreviousData in your use case? I think it internally changes the "initialData" therefore making your resets not work as expected.

yeah, i need it :(
